# What is an efficient data structure to read/write IPv6 address ranges into for quick lookup times?

Tags: java, algorithm, networking, optimization, data-structures

I'm trying to think of an efficient data structure which I can use to store IPv6 address ranges into. The lookup time should be quick. That is, given an IPv6 address, I should be able to quickly determine which interval it's from. In my case here, address ranges DO NOT overlap.

One efficient way would be to create a simple binary search tree, and each non-leaf node would simply be 'redirecting lookup traffic'. The PROBLEM with this approach however is that the size of the BST would be really big, in the order of 2^128 nodes maybe, which I might not be able to read/write to a file.

So what data structure can I use for quick IPv6 address lookup that also has a lower upper bound on filesize ???

I am using Java by the way.

Comment: Can you use third party libraries?  Guava's RangeSet is suitable for this.

Comment: If the ranges do not overlap, you may be able to use a hash table.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but… the Postgres database has native [data types for network addresses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html) built-in, offers [functions for working with such addresses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html), and I am guessing could perform range searches.

Comment: can we just sort the intervals and do binary search?

Answer (score 2):

There's a perfectly good data-structure for this, called an interval tree.
It's based on an ordinary binary search tree.
But, instead of storing keys, it stores intervals. And supports lookup of a value. It can return the node in which a key was found. Since a node contains its bounds, that makes it easy to implement your usecase.

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what is the theoretical upper bound on number of nodes that will be needed at most ?

Comment: I don't know the upper bound by heart. I have seen however that the wikipedia article has example java code in it. You can always copy/paste the code and simply write a test to figure out the bounds.
Or do some googling.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to define intervals about IPv6, then you can use trie data structure, I believe.

Some documentations about an implementation of tries.

- https://community.oracle.com/thread/2070706
- http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-trie/